# Copy values from txt file to a specific location in another one - Script Shell

Tags: bash, shell

and thanks for the help.
I have a txt file serving as a template : 
===Template.txt==========================================================

```
BT-qos- profile = "ABCDEF",
BT-type- collecte = "%{Request}",
BT-sous- type-collecte = "%{Request}",
Framed-IP- Address = "XX.XX.XX.XX",
Framed-IP- Netmask = "255.255.255.240",
BT-domain = "bbox.fr",
```

=====Ips_file.txt==========================================================

```
10.20.30.40
11.22.33.44
111.222.333.444
(each ip is in a line)
```

======================================================================
I want to create a shell script that can read the ips from the second file and copy each ip and put in the first file where the "XX.XX.XX.XX" .
After each copy save the file.I will have as many files as I have of Ips.

I am not familiar with shell scripts,so I would appreciate if somebody can help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how you want to name those files.
For simplicity, let's name them with increasing numbers.
You could read the ips line by line,
and use `sed` to replace the values in the template and produce the output files:

```
placeholder='XX\.XX\.XX\.XX'

i=1
while IFS= read -r ip; do
    sed -e "s/$placeholder/$ip/" Template.txt > $i.txt
    ((i++))
done < Ips_file.txt
```

Comment: Thx u so much.That's what I was looking for.I'll customise your answer and adapt it to my needs.
Have a wonderful Day/night Mister :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this an `awk` as well:

```
awk 'FILENAME=="template.txt"{template=template$0"\n"} FILENAME=="ips_file.txt"{template_out=template; gsub(/XX\.XX\.XX\.XX/,$1, template_out); print template_out > $1".txt"}' template.txt ips_file.txt
```

That will create a new file for each IP names by the ip address with a`.txt` appended to it